# How to start AnimatorSet consecutively?

Tags: android, animation

I want to run multiple AnimatorSet on a view. AnimatorSet should run consecutively one after another. I want to do it without using handler for time delay. How can I do it?

Comment: I tried using that but there's an exception that animator set object gets released.

Comment: I have separate class for creating and running animator set. whenever I need to create or run an animator set I use its instance. If I invoke run AnimatorSet method consecutively that it gives exception.

Comment: Yes. I have already.

Comment: If I have two sets then first animation gets skipped and second runs. And I know the reason which is, if a set is running then next set should be delayed.

Comment: No that doesn't work.

Comment: I cant use playsequentially method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your code.

```
AnimatorSet bouncer = new AnimatorSet();
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTextView, "rotationX", 0f, 180f);
anim.setDuration(2000);
ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTextView, "rotationX", 180f, 0f);
anim2.setDuration(2000);
ObjectAnimator anim3 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTextView, "rotationY", 0f, 180f);
anim3.setDuration(2000);
ObjectAnimator anim4 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTextView, "rotationY", 180f, 0f);
anim4.setDuration(2000);

bouncer.playSequentially(anim, anim2, anim3, anim4);
bouncer.start();
```

**Note**

method:

1. play (Animator anim);

   ```
   play (Animator anim):  // add an animation and return AnimatorSet.Builder
   ```
2. playSequentially(List items);

   ```
   playSequentially (List items):  // add a set of animations, play sequentially, and play them one by one
   ```
3. playSequentially (Animator... Items);

   ```
   playSequentially (Animator... Items):   // add a set of animations, play sequentially, and play them one by one
   ```
4. playTogether (Collection items);

   ```
   playTogether (Collection items):   // add a set of animations, played sequentially, and played together
   ```
5. playTogether (Animator... Items);

   ```
    playTogether (Animator... Items):   // add a set of animations, play sequentially, and play together
   ```

Comment: This gives exception in my case.

Comment: Change `mTextView` to your `View`.

Comment: Could you show your code to us ? Then we can give some suggestion to you.

Comment: Could you show the exception you said ?@ruchitathombre